# How to execute bash commands as non root user from Python?

Tags: python, service

I am trying to use aquatone from python. It works fine when I run it from VS Code or terminal using either os or subprocess. But When it is start from a parent program which is started on startup as a service. It doesn't work anymore. My guess is that it is due to the parent program being run as root.
The parent program requires root privileges.
So is there any way to I can start the aquatone as a non-root user from within python??

Answer (score 1):

It depends where you've installed `aquatone`. By default, if you're using `pip`, `aquatone` will be installed to `python/site-packages` so in order to access the package and Python interpreter any app that runs Python will need to be granted root privileges. This is the simplest way to solve the problem.

Comment: aquatone is a binary program.